# (Django) ForeignKey and Comment: Having a problem trying to save the username of the user who posts the comment

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to emulate the comment functionality of Instagram. the problem is that the 'username' key of each new comment only takes the user_id number instead of the actual username and I can't figure out a way to fix this despite all the documentation readings. Below are my codes.

comment/views.py

```
import json
import jwt

from django.views           import View
from django.http            import JsonResponse
from functools              import wraps
from django.db.models       import Q

from .models                    import Comment
from account.models   import Account

def login_required(func):
        #@wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            given_token     = json.loads(request.body)['access_token']
            decoded_token   = jwt.decode(given_token,'secret', algorithm='HS256')['username']

            try:
                if Account.objects.filter(username=decoded_token).exists():

                    return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({"message": "username does not exist"})
            except KeyError:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "INVALID_KEYS"}, status=403)
        return wrapper


class CommentView(View):

    @login_required
    def post(self, request):

        data            = json.loads(request.body)
        given_token     = json.loads(request.body)['access_token']
        decoded_token   = jwt.decode(given_token,'secret', algorithm='HS256')['username']
        account         = Account.objects.get(username=decoded_token)

        Comment.objects.create(
                username    = account.username,
                content     = data['content'],
        )
        return JsonResponse({"message":"Comment Created!"}, status=200)

    def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({'comment':list(Comment.objects.values())}, status=200)
```

account/models.py

```
from django.db                      import models

class Account(models.Model):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length = 254, null=True)
    password    = models.CharField(max_length=700)
    fullname    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'accounts'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username + " " + self.fullname + " " + str(self.email) + " " + str(self.phone)
```

comment/models.py

```
from django.db                  import models
from account.models   import Account

class Comment(models.Model):
    username    = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content     = models.TextField()
    created_time= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_time= models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'comments'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username + ": " + self.content
```

This is what I put in as POST request:

```
http -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment access_token="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImJlY2sifQ.2unop67pLHOshcGs385GwOvaZZW_J--TRNXyHI3gKNU" content="hello"

http -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment access_token="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImJlY2sifQ.2unop67pLHOshcGs385GwOvaZZW_J--TRNXyHI3gKNU" content="is anyone there?"
```

This is what I find in the shell:

```
>>> Comment.objects.all().values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'username_id': 2, 'content': 'hello', 'created_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 11, 13, 0, 235510, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 11, 13, 0, 235535, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'id': 2, 'username_id': 2, 'content': 'is anyone there?', 'created_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 11, 13, 32, 604872, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 11, 13, 32, 604890, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]>
```

Again, it saves only username_id, not the username itself...

Thanks a lot and have a good week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model logic is wrong. Because, foreignkey connect a models to another one, not field. I mean that, in your Comment models, `username` field stores Account model object reference. So firstly, I suggest change your field name with `account`. After that, you can use account object when you create new Comment object. You have already got `account` object in your code with `Account.objects.get(username=decoded_token)`. You can pass this `account` object to Comment model with:

```
 Comment.objects.create(
            account    = account, # your new renamed field
            content     = data['content'],
    )
```

If you need access to username from comment in anywhere, you can use this:

```
comment.account.username
```